# how to schedule different tumbling window trigger times in dev and prod environments

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

We have azure synapse studios in dev and prod environments and for one of the pipelines we have a tumbling window trigger setup. We also have Azure Devops release pipelines setup to release the Synapse workspace from Dev to Prod. For this tumbling window pipeline we would like to have different trigger time in dev and prod, but the release always overwrites the trigger time.
How do I achieve this?

Not tried any thing.

Comment: To confirm the trigger configuration, are you creating the tumbling window triggers in the Azure portal instead of Azure Pipeline? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-tumbling-window-trigger?tabs=synapse-analytics%2Cazure-powershell

Comment: I am creating the trigger in Azure Synapse studio. We have Azure synapse workspace with Azure devops repository. We have setup release pipelines in Azure Devops so that when we publish the latest workspace in dev Synapse workspace it is deployed from Dev to Prod.